# cd error - file path not character vector Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, character, cd, strcat

This is probably and easy matlab question but I am really struggling with this one:

I am building a for loop to go through a directory of folders and open a file (filename.csv) within each uniquely named folder. Thus, I have defined my `filepath` within my loop so that it opens each correct folder and then the correct file within. I am getting hung up, however, on simply concatenating my `filepath` within the loop, changing the directory to the appropriate folder and then opening the file. Here is the code (outside the for loop with just i=1, for simplicity sake):

```
drive = dir()
namelist = dir(drive)
filepath = strcat(drive, namelist[1])
cd(filepath)
x = xlsread('filename.csv')
```

I have also tried defining the filepath as the path of the file itself:

```
filepath = strcat(drive, namelist[1], '\filename.csv')
x = xlsread(filepath)
```

Both methods produce an error message when using `cd` or when using `xlsread` that 'arguments must contain a character vector'.

I have also tried using `fullfile` instead of `strcat`, to no avail.

Comment: What is `dir`? Do you have a variable or function defined with that name? `dir` is a built-in function which returns the file list as a struct array. Your usage does not seem to suggest that you are calling the built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

[`dir()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html?s_tid=doc_ta) return a struct array in your current directory. So `drive = dir()` will give you a struct array `drive`. For example:

```
drive = 
  81×1 struct array with fields:
    name
    folder
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

According to your problem, first, to get a list of directory names, you can do this:

```
drive = dir()
namelist = {drive([drive(:).isdir]).name}
```

This will give you a cell array of directory names.

Since `.` and `..` are the current directory and parent directory. You might want to delete these two (Usually, they are the first and second element):

```
namelist(1) = []
namelist(1) = []
```

Then, to get to the path of those directories, you can do this:

```
for i =1:length(namelist)
    filepath = strcat(pwd, '\', namelist{i},'\filename.csv')
    x = csvread(filepath)
end
```

Comment: The `find` is unnecessary in `namelist = {drive(find([drive(:).isdir])).name}`, logical indexing with  `namelist = {drive([drive(:).isdir]).name}` will work.

Comment: Right! Thanks for the catch!